# PHP Sessions Security: Storing sessions in DB vs. Changing sessions save path?

Tags: php, session

I am trying to create a more secure PHP sessions login script. Unfortunately for this project I will be working with shared hosting. Would using PHP's `session_save_path()` function to change the path to something other than `/tmp` be a secure solution? Or do I need to save the sessions in the database?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving the session save path is a good start. Just make sure its not in the document root.

With some shared hosted I've observed that getting a database connection can take a second or two. Storing your sessions in the db could slow the whole app down. Your session is accessed twice per page load.

You may want to test both an see which performs better.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I prefer storing sessions in the database because it not only circumvents some of the file access slowdowns associated with using a file-based system, but also gives you more direct and "supervised" methods of managing the direct session data.

Consider, if you implement using MySQL, using the [Memory (HEAP) Storage Engine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/memory-storage-engine.html) as it will give enormous performance benefits.  This, of course, is assuming you are unlikely to have thousands upon thousands of active sessions, and that your session data is "volatile safe," i.e. if a sever crash causes session data to be lost, the worst that should happen will be that users are asked to log back in.